# Why is there an action being performed when I'm only trying to assign a variable?

Tags: python, powerpoint

I'm trying to reorganize the below code

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_LABEL_POSITION
from pptx.util import Pt

prs = Presentation('test.pptx')
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_chart:
            continue
        chart = shape.chart
        for series in chart.series:      
            for point, value in zip(series.points, series.values):
                if value >= 7.5:
                    fill = point.format.fill
                    fill.solid()
                    fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 176, 80)
                elif value < 7.5 and value >= 3.5:
                    fill = point.format.fill
                    fill.solid()
                    fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 192, 0)
                    data_label = point.data_label
                    data_label.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.CENTER
                    font = data_label.font
                    font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)
                    font.size = Pt(9)
                elif value <3.5 and value > 1:
                    fill = point.format.fill
                    fill.solid()
                    fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
prs.save('testoutput.pptx')
```

Into the following code

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_LABEL_POSITION
from pptx.util import Pt

prs = Presentation('test.pptx')
for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_chart:
            continue
        chart = shape.chart
        for series in chart.series:
            for point, value in zip(series.points, series.values):          
                fill = point.format.fill
                fill.solid()
                data_label = point.data_label
                font = data_label.font
                if value >= 7.5:                    
                    fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 176, 80)
                elif value < 7.5 and value >= 3.5:                    
                    fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 192, 0)                    
                    data_label.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.CENTER                    
                    font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0, 0, 0)
                    font.size = Pt(9)
                elif value <3.5 and value > 1:                    
                    fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)
prs.save('testoutput.pptx')
```

Where variables get assigned up front and then used throughout the rest of the if statements (fill, data_label, font). To me everything looks good in the code, but I'm obviously missing something because the outputs are different:

Original slide being manipulated (test.pptx)

[image]

Correct output from code 1:

[image]

Incorrect output from code 2:

[image]

Comment: It looks like merely accessing `point.data_label` is causing some default values to be applied - the only real difference I see between your two code versions is that the second one is unconditionally accessing that attribute, while the first one only accesses it in the 3.5-7.5 case where the label position gets set.  Since it seems that you *want* centered positioning in all cases, I'd suggest setting `data_label.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.CENTER` unconditionally.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the response! If you notice the output, the fill and font also get changed on the left graph. What you're saying would solve one of the 3 issues, but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps counter-intuitively, a series "point" does not (normally) exist until you access it. So iterating over the points is a destructive operation in that the inheritance of certain chart marker (bar in this case) properties is disrupted.

PowerPoint gets around this by assigning all the current values to the point when it is created. In the UI a point is created by selecting the individual bar and editing something about it.

Consequently, you need to assign certain properties to every point you visit. You can be selective about that by traversing values separately and then only accessing the points that you are going to change.

Maybe something like:

```
for idx, value in enumerate(series.values):          
    if value < 1:
        continue
    point = series.points[idx]
    # --- do pointy operations ---
```

But as soon as you access the point, you need to set all the attributes for which you don't want the defaults.